# Retrieve Google API JSON data and store as WordPress Custom Fields

Tags: custom-field, api

I am trying to use Google Places API with WordPress. I am trying to create a function where I get the API data and store it as custom fields.

I found a [similar answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187541/google-places-api-with-acf), but it only deals with cache.

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/store-json-in-a-custom-field?rq=1) helped but not in detail.

I want to use wp_remote_get() to retrieve JSON data.

My goal is to access any the custom fields data using get_post_meta() in single.php

Comment: so what is the question? how to use the google api itself is off-topic here

Comment: what is the problem with storing key,pair as a custom field? key is the meta key, and pair is the value for example

Comment: the function in my question is not working I don't know what I am doing wrong? After adding the place_id  its suppose to auto populate or update the other custom fields

Comment: you need ot debug what is it that you are getting from the api

Answer (score 0):

I found out how I can store JSON data into a custom field. I completely forgot to use add_action.

Here is my answer below I added to functions.php.

You have to add custom field place_id and its value then click 'publish or 'update' for the other fields to populate.

```
    function google_places_data( $post = null ) {
    if ( ! $post = get_post( $post ) )
        return;
    if ( ! $place_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'place_id', true ) )
        return; // No place ID configured for this post

    if ( $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'place_data', true ) ) {
        if ( $data->timeout <= current_time( 'timestamp' ) )
            $data = null; // Void the cache if it's old
    }

    if ( ! $data ) {
        $args = http_build_query(
            array(
                'key' => 'AIzaSyCarm54WzOXFhXqmEU3rkUorDoa8b3Nzog', // API key
                'placeid' => $place_id
                )
            );

        $http = wp_remote_get( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?$args" );
        if ( $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $http ) ) {
            if ( $data =@ json_decode( $body ) )
                $data->timeout = current_time( 'timestamp' ) + HOUR_IN_SECONDS; // Cache data for 1 hour

            $place_address = $data->result->formatted_address; 
            $place_lat = $data->result->geometry->location->lat;
            $place_long = $data->result->geometry->location->lng; 
            $place_phone = '000-000-010';

            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'place_address', $place_address );
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'place_lat', $place_lat );
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'place_long', $place_long );
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'place_phone', $place_phone );

        }

        if ( $data ) {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'place_data', $data );

        } else {
            echo 'api error';
        }

    }

    return $data;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'google_places_data', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Would it be possible to ask you some questions regarding this answer?